# mysql order by select -- possible?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here is my table setup:

```
mysql> describe a;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| x     | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| y     | varchar(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe b;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| a     | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| z     | varchar(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from a;
+----+------+------+
| id | x    | y    |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    | 
|  2 |    2 | b    | 
|  3 |    3 | c    | 
|  4 |    4 | d    | 
+----+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from b;
+----+---+------+
| id | a | z    |
+----+---+------+
|  1 | 3 | q    | 
|  2 | 2 | a    | 
|  3 | 1 | u    | 
|  4 | 4 | x    | 
+----+---+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
mysql> select a.* from a, b where a.id = b.a order by b.z;
+----+------+------+
| id | x    | y    |
+----+------+------+
|  2 |    2 | b    | 
|  3 |    3 | c    | 
|  1 |    1 | a    | 
|  4 |    4 | d    | 
+----+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I want to use a syntax like "SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY (SELECT a FROM b ORDER BY z)".

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the problem with just using "select a.* from a, b where a.id = b.a order by b.z;"?

Comment: Other than the ugly old-style join, that is.

Answer (score 14):

Sorting by a Subquery is possible as long as the Subquery returns exactly 1 result, what means you need to join the tables within the subquery.

I just setup this in a query-builder within my application, something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a,b
WHERE a.id = b.a
ORDER BY (
   SELECT z
   FROM b
   WHERE a.id = b.a
) ASC
```

Comment: The outer `WHERE` is not needed. Also you need to add `LIMIT 1` to the sub-query. Maybe that wasn't required back in '12 :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY (SELECT a FROM b ORDER BY z)
```

No, this will not get you what you want.  In the first place, the subquery returns more than one row, so it can't be used as an expressions in the `ORDER BY` of the outer query.  This is the error you get:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Also, there's no correlation between the rows of `a` and the order of the rows in the subquery, given that form of query.  In other words, even if you've sorted the values in the subquery, that doesn't make the rows of the outer query sort in a matching order.

If you're trying to ensure only a single row in the result set per row if `a` (even when there are multiple matching rows in `b`), then you probably want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM a JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a)
ORDER BY b.z;
```

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think that it's possible the way you describe it, I think that you will need to to join the tables.

Look this up : http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_inner.asp